# Random Click Count on Left Click With Mouse

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse

I'm hoping someone can help me out with this, because the effects are driving me crazy.  Basically, left-clicking with my mouse delivers a random number of clicks each time.  Sometimes there's no click, sometimes one, and sometimes multiple in rapid succession.  This makes it nearly impossible to do most things, as something as simple as closing a tab in Chrome could lead to clearing out a bunch of tabs in rapid succession.

I know it's not the mouse, as I've swapped multiple mice onto this computer, and every one shows the same symptoms.  I tried both using a USB bar and plugging the mice into the computer directly, and I've swapped between USB ports, and that doesn't change anything.  I'm not sure what else to try to fix this problem; nothing I've found in Windows seems to have any kind of effect on this.

Answer (score 0):

We can try to troubleshoot the issue as below:

1. Put the mouse on another computer to see if there is such a problem.
2. Does the computer have other mouse devices set up, such as a touchpad, stylus, etc.
3. Try uninstalling the mouse in the device manager, reloading the mouse driver.
4. Update the motherboard driver according to the model of the computer